# PHP Session Array - store same item with different values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, shopping-cart

i'm working on a PHP cart system and i have got a problem.

**The Problem:**

When a user adds an item and then again, adds that same item but with different values like (different size or quantity) the cart updates that entry with new values that's chosen by the user. previous details gets deleted.

**Solution i have been looking for**

If users adds any item, and then wants to add that same item but with different requirements, should be added as a separate entry int the cart session.(only if the specific variable gets changed, for example: A single product but with different sizes).

How can i do this in my current code?

**The Cart**

```
//add item in shopping cart
if(isset($_POST["type"]) && $_POST["type"]=='add')
{
    $product_code   = filter_var($_POST["product_code"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //product code
    $product_size   = filter_var($_POST["product_size"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT); //product size
    $product_qty    = filter_var($_POST["product_qty"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT); //product quantity
    $return_url     = base64_decode($_POST["return_url"]); //return url


    //MySqli query - get details of item from db using product code
    $results = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE prod_code='$product_code' LIMIT 1");
    $obj = $results->fetch_object();

    if ($results) { //we have the product info 

        //prepare array for the session variable
        $new_product = array(array('name'=>$obj->product_name, 'code'=>$product_code, 'size'=>$product_size, 'qty'=>$product_qty, 'price'=>$obj->price));

        if(isset($_SESSION["products"])) //if we have the session
        {
            $found = false; //set found item to false

            foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as $cart_itm) //loop through session array
            {
                if($cart_itm["code"] == $product_code){ //the item exist in array

                    $product[] = array('name'=>$cart_itm["name"], 'code'=>$cart_itm["code"], 'size'=>$product_size, 'qty'=>$product_qty, 'price'=>$cart_itm["price"]);
                    $found = true;
                }else{
                    //item doesn't exist in the list, just retrieve old info and prepare array for session var
                    $product[] = array('name'=>$cart_itm["name"], 'code'=>$cart_itm["code"], 'size'=>$cart_itm["size"], 'qty'=>$cart_itm["qty"], 'price'=>$cart_itm["price"]);
                }
            }

            if($found == false) //we didn't find item in array
            {
                //add new user item in array
                $_SESSION["products"] = array_merge($product, $new_product);
            }else{
                //found user item in array list, and increased the quantity
                $_SESSION["products"] = $product;
            }

        }else{
            //create a new session var if does not exist
            $_SESSION["products"] = $new_product;
        }

    }

    //redirect back to original page
    header('Location:'.$return_url);
}
```

Looking forward for some helpful answers.

Thanks

***** UPDATE ******

Code to remove Product From Cart:

```
//remove item from shopping cart
if(isset($_GET["removep"]) && isset($_GET["return_url"]) && isset($_SESSION["products"]))
{
    $product_code   = $_GET["removep"]; //get the product code to remove
    $return_url     = base64_decode($_GET["return_url"]); //get return url


    foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as $cart_itm) //loop through session array var
    {
        //if($cart_itm["code"]!=$product_code){ //item does,t exist in the list
        if($cart_itm["code"] != $product_code && $cart_itm["size"] != $product_size){
            $product[] = array(
            'name'=>$cart_itm["name"],
            'code'=>$cart_itm["code"],
            'size'=>$cart_itm["size"],
            'qty'=>$cart_itm["qty"],
            'price'=>$cart_itm["price"]
            );
        }

        //create a new product list for cart
        $_SESSION["products"] = $product;
    }

    //redirect back to original page
    header('Location:'.$return_url);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `if` condition that you are using is the mistake that you did. Try this one

```
if($cart_itm["code"] == $product_code && $cart_itm["size"] == $product_size)
```

instead of

```
if($cart_itm["code"] == $product_code)
```

The method of checking with the quantity is not good practice since you can edit the quantity alone in the already existing entry.

Comment: Now the items adding separately, which is the answer i was looking. But there's an issue with the deletion. all items gets deleted because The `$product_code` is same how to do this? i applied this same condition `if($cart_itm["code"] !== $product_code && $cart_itm["size"] !== $product_size){`

Comment: @yaqoob your condition in the comment is neither the same nor the opposite of sujivasagam's  condition. The code you are referring to are also not shown.  Please ask a new question on that part

Comment: use the same condition in negative format as 'if($cart_itm["code"] != $product_code && $cart_itm["size"] != $product_size)'

Comment: @sujivasagam: i didn't work, i'm adding the remove product code in question, please check.

Comment: need more explanation. When can you delete the item from cart? While clicking the delete button corresponding to that?

Comment: @sujivasagam when any item i tried to delete it removes all the items with that same `$product_code`. instead it should only delete the selected item. for example i have a single product with 3 different sizes there are 3 rows in the cart, but if i delete any one of them they are all deleted.

Comment: $product_code   = $_GET["removep"];  is the place where you get the product code to remove right? there why didn't you include the size of the product need to delete?

Comment: why didn't you use the primary key of the cart entry there or check the product code and the size? where did you delete the entry? i can't find the place where you delete the cart entry

Comment: so i have to get the `$cart_itm["size"]` as well?

Comment: yes. either you have to compare with the product code & size or the primary id used for that cart entry is the correct method

Comment: I am not clear with your removal code to say how to do. On clicking the delete button, you have to check the product code & the size of that item and then need to delete that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79305/discussion-between-yaqoob-and-sujivasagam).

Answer (score 2):

You need to work out a cart item code which is unique to make it work. Either you could combine the product code with size or quantity, or use something like a GUID to store separate cart item.

A combined key has an issue when changing size or quantity. Using GUIDs requires a little work, but is a viable and solid solution.

Comment: updated my question with the code for "item deletion"

Answer (score 0):

try declaring the `$product` as array in the beginning.

```
$product = array();
```

Hope this helps.